# Trying to use getIntent() within a custom dialog comes up as an error. Solution to get around this error?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-dialog

I am sending a string from an activity to my custom dialog.
This is the activity in which I create a bundle and insert the string, then send it to the dialog activity.

```
Bundle sendToDialog = new Bundle();
sendToDialog.putString("caloreis", strCalories);
Intent a = new Intent(CaloriesLogMainActivity.this, ActivityDialog.class);
a.putExtras(sendToDialog);
```

This is the custom dialog activity in which I am trying to receive the intent from the activity.
getIntent(), is coming up as an error.  How would I get around this error?

```
public class ActivityDialog {
    Context mContext;
     Date mDate;
    public ActivityDialog(Context context, CaloriesLogMainActivity caloriesLogMainActivity) {
        mContext = context;

    }  
    public void show() {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_activity, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder((mContext));
        final EditText calories = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etCalories);

        Bundle recieveFromActivity = getIntent().getExtras();
        String strCaloreis = recieveFromActivity.getString("calories");
        calories.setText(strCaloreis);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.edit_log_title);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.create_log_negative_button,
                new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });

        builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.create_log_neutral_button, null);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.create_log_positive_button, null);
        builder.create().show();

        builder.setView(view);
        builder.create().show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Does `ActivityDialog` extend `Activity`?  It would need to in order for you to call `getIntent()`.  What is the error that you are seeing, exactly?

Comment: No it Does not. The getintent is underlined red.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly the problem then.  All of your Activities should extend the class `Activity` regardless, but specifically your problem is due to the fact that `getIntent()` is defined in `Activity` so you need to extend that in order to use it.  Also note the typo pointed out in Mark N's answer :)

Comment: Thank you.  Post Your answer below so I can accept your answer

Comment: There, I just have.  One other note I just thought of, once this class extends Activity, it will have a proper Context of its own.  In that case, I think you should be able to remove the constructor and the `mContext` variable, and then refactor the Activity to use more traditional lifecycle methods such as `onCreate()` etc.  Otherwise, I'm not sure that this will work as expected.  Also, if you just want this dialog showing in another Activity, you may consider having it extend `AlertDialog` instead and pass your string through a constructor rather than an `Intent`.  Just my two cents though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ActivityDialog` class is an Activity and thus should extend `Activity`.  This is a general rule, but specifically your problem here is due to the fact that `getIntent()` is defined in `Activity`, so you must extend that in order to use it.

Answer (score 2):

you have to extend Activity class , then only you can access getIntent()...

so your code should be like this

```
public class ActivityDialog extends Activity{
    Context mContext;
     Date mDate;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   //here you can call getIntent()
 }
    public void show() {
     // or even from here ,you can call getIntent()
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_activity, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder((mContext));
        final EditText calories = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etCalories);

        Bundle recieveFromActivity = getIntent().getExtras();
        String strCaloreis = recieveFromActivity.getString("calories");
        calories.setText(strCaloreis);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.edit_log_title);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.create_log_negative_button,
                new OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });

        builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.create_log_neutral_button, null);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.create_log_positive_button, null);
        builder.create().show();

        builder.setView(view);
        builder.create().show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of your spelling mistake in `sendToDialog.putString("caloreis", strCalories);` because you later reference the extra as "calories" not "caloreis". (I tried to put this in an edit but it was uner 6 characters long...)

Comment: Sorry for not getting back.  I change the text just for display purposes and messed up on the question but it is fine in my original code.